# C++14 RAM Usage

Tags: c++

On submitting a solution on SPOJ, I've found that my program used 16M of memory even though my program used a single integer variable.

Is this natural or am I missing something?

```
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
    int x;
    while(true)
    {
        std::cin >> x;
        if(x == 42)
        {
            break;
        }
        std::cout << x << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The compiler used is gcc 6.

[image: Submission Info]

Comment: That really depends on what the "16M" is for. You need space for the executable program itself (which might be larger than you think if it contains debug information), then space for all runtime libraries needed, then space for the C++ runtime data (like e.g. `std::cin` etc.). Then of course it depends on the operating system what is allocates and pads heap and other data to. And of course the stack needs space as well, and on Linux it's by default 8M per process. And so on...

Comment: But the ones on the leaderboard do not seem to have this issue : https://www.spoj.com/ranks/TEST/

Comment: Those are all from 2004, perhaps the environment of the grading system changed in the meantime and that's why it's taking up more memory now. Even then the C solutions still use 1.5M, and also note that 0.9M difference between the C and C++ submissions.

Comment: The biggest mistake a compiler and operating system could make with the gigabytes of memory available on a modern machine is not use it.  Progress.

Comment: try using stdio over iostream. it may or may not help. If you are in control of compilation/linking flags you may be able to strip debug info out and optimize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fairly natural if you're running with debug info (the strip command in a makefile will pull that out) and if you're building optimized or non-optimized.

Try adding -s and -O to your GCC command if not already. This will build your executable optimized to a decent degree and strip the symbol tables from the executable as well as a few other things. Should reduce your memory usage significantly.

If you want further optimizations on your memory you can also custom set the stack size with GCC, you can try to reduce it to the KB to make some ground there too.

All in all for an unoptimized/debug loaded executable this is fairly normal.

Comment: I can't set that in the SPOJ site. Thanks